# Rename columns that are exactly same

Tags: duplicates

I have an Excel file with two columns "Super Type". I've imported this Excel file into a DataFrame without directly opening it due to its large size. However, now that it's in my DataFrame, I've encountered a problem because both columns have the exact same name. What steps should I take to address this issue? The rename techniques did not help me.

I did this :

```
duplicate_columns = df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep=False)]
for col in duplicate_columns:
  df.rename(columns={col: col + "_2"}, inplace=True)
```

but after that, I again had two columns the with same name.

Comment: Please use proper tags in your post to specify the scope of your question and let experts find your question